# response.statusText="OK" but falls into error callback from ajax with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Server side:

```
 ....
    $_SESSION['accountId'] = $accountId;
    $_SESSION['type'] = $_POST['accountType'];
    echo '1';
    return;
```

Client side:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type:'POST',
    data: $("#flowFormSubmit").serialize(),
    dataType:'text/plain',
    timeout:1000,
    success:function(response){
        if(-1 == response)
            alert('fail');
        else
            alert('succeed');
    }
});
```

I've tested that it stops right at 'return;'
Under what conditions will success function not be called?

**EDIT**:

after adding error callback,it's caught,but didn't output useful information yet:

```
error:function(response){ alert(response);alert(response.statusText); },
```

It outputs only:

```
[object XMLHttpRequest]  
OK
```

Why does it fall in error callback?

Comment: Please add an error callback.  It might be firing and will perhaps help to shed light on the issue.

Comment: Is the return statement within your server-side code necessary?

Comment: yes,it's neccesary.And server side operation is finished,why it still falls into error callback?

Comment: inspect the properties of the XMLHttpRequest object passed to your error callback.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: response.statusText is "OK",but still falls into error callback.Really weird!

Comment: what about status and responseText?

Answer (score 3):

There are more useful parameters to the error callback.  Try getting the textStatus.

```
error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus); }
```

Check what that is.

A quick guess is that you meant to use `dataType: 'text'` not `'text/plain'`.  ([Check documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options))

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data: $("#flowFormSubmit").serialize(),
    dataType:'text',
    timeout:1000,
    success:function(response){
        if(-1 == response)
                alert('fail');
        else
                alert('succeed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be a good idea to specify a [URL option](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options):

```
$.ajax(
{
    url:'foo.php',
    type:'POST',
    ...
```

Comment: astounding that he gets to the 'return'

Comment: The recipient URL is probably the same as the requesting URL, so perhaps jQuery uses a reasonable default (i.e, the current page).

Comment: doh! I didn't notice that. hmmmm

Comment: yeah, it does default to the current page

Comment: @Davis Andres - you are right, it defaults to the current page.

Comment: @All: It's nice to learn something seemingly by accident or by some sense of reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try omitting the return statement from server-side code.  As far as your error callback is concerned, use the following generic ajax callback code and let us know what the status, responseText, and statusText properties are when this fails:

```
function callback(response)
{
  if (response.readyState == 4) 
  {
    if (response.status == 200) 
    {
      alert("Response Success:\n" + response.responseText);
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Response Error:\n" + response.statusText);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Really weird,success callback sometimes get called,sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

did you forget:

```
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
```

on server?

Answer (score 0):

1) go to the url in your browser (the one you're fetching with ajax)

2) set the error callback for the jquery ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

in your php code, use json_encode to return the response

eg:

```
$response = array('success'=>1);
echo json_encode($response);
```

then in your ajax success function it should be

```
if (response.success == 1) { alert('success'); }
```