# html tags in data returned from json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a php page that is returning some data in json.  Basically I am doing echo on this page.

The data being returned has some html tags.  This is causing my jQuery code to break.

Is there a way to clean up the data and strip off the tags before putting it in the json object?

Furthermore, I am trying to display the data from json into a textarea and ideally I would like to show the html tags in the textarea...

Comment: is it necessary that you use json? .. would not a simple $('textarea#id').load() suffice?

Comment: I think the PHP response includes the basic <html><head><body> response.  Somewhere in this markup is the OP's JSON text.  Is there a way to clear the response prior to echo'ing the JSON text?

Comment: It would be nice to see an example, as I am curious if you have quotes within the html.

Comment: Stealing liberally from another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414205/cant-get-response-from-ajax-with-jquery): he may need to specify header('Content-Type:text/plain'); on the server-side.

Comment: This is too vague to answer. Please show us your code, so we can tell if you're sending the wrong thing from the server, or doing the wrong thing on the client side. Basically it sounds like you're not escaping/encoding your data properly, but it's hard to say where yet.

Comment: Are the HTML tags you want to strip, the same ones you want show in the textarea? Or are they different. Example input and output would be great.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the json, you can use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the values that have html in your php code - this will escape the values in json so that it validates and will be usable in jquery. I haven't tried it, but you should not have a problem adding the value to a textarea.