# JSON messing up when data returned has HTML tags

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a PHP page that is returning a JSON object like this:

```
  header('Content-Type:application/json');
  echo <<<HERE_DOC
      [ {content: '{row2[contentFull]}', bigimages: '{$row3['catalogFileID']}'}]
      HERE_DOC;
```

In my main page I have the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function()
{
  jQuery("select#rooms").change(function()
  {
    var options = '';

    jQuery.getJSON("/admin/selection_about.php",{id:jQuery(this).val(), 
                   ajax:isAjax}, function(j)
    {
       for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) 
       {
          options = j[i].topImage;
          document.getElementById('content1').value = j[i].bigimages;
       }
    })
  })
})
```

So basically in my main page, I have a drop down.  When an option is selected, it fires off an Ajax request back to the server. I get the data in JSON format and then a textarea, with ID 'content1', is updated based on that JSON object.

The JSON object looks like this:

```
[ 
  {  
     content: '<SPAN STYLE= "" >&quot;
     this is some text&quot; 
     blah blah, &quot;
     some more `text&quot;  
     now some linebreaks; 
     <BR><BR>some more text and then another` linebreak.`<BR>`</SPAN>',
     bigimages: 'cfil1069'
   }
]`
```

But there are errors that occur here and my textarea does not get updated. However, if I hardcode plain simple text to be returned in the JSON object, then my textarea is updated.

Is there a condition for which data in the JSON object should not have HTML tags?

Edit:

As suggested, I changed my code to following in PHP code:

```
$arr = array ('content'=>$rest1,'bigimages'=>$row3['catalogFileID']);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

However now in my jQuery code:

length of j is 'undefined' ...

```
    jQuery.getJSON("/admin/selection_about.php",{id: jQuery(this).val(), 
                   ajax: isAjax}, function(j)
    {
       alert('here3: ' + j.length); // this shows undefined

       for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) 
       {
          document.getElementById('content1').value = j[i].content;
       }
    })
```

Comment: directly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414213/html-tags-in-data-returned-from-json

Comment: also directly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414205/cant-get-response-from-ajax-with-jquery

Comment: @David Andres: Yes, but 1414213 has been asked by the same user (though no answer has been provided yet).

Answer (score 1):

Put your content into a PHP array. Then convert it to JSON using `json_encode()`.
That will safely encode and escape the characters, for example double quotes in your HTML attribute.

**UPDATE:**

The reason why `j.length` does not work is because:
An PHP array with keys are not Javascript arrays. Javascript arrays have no keys. Thus when converted, the PHP array is converted into a JS object.

Instead to access your JS object, you can use `j.content`, instead of looping through the object with `j.length`. `j.length` is undefined because there is no property in the object `j` with the property name `length` (that is because in your PHP array, there is no `$arr['length']`)

Comment: doing that makes my code break. Before echoing back json_encode() I was accessing elements of json object as j.content but now that code is breaking. Should it be accessed some other way? as I noticed that data returned from json now is "content":"something" ...rather than content:"something"

Comment: it doens't break the code if it's written "content":"something", in javascript it is still valid.